# php70-fpm doesn't include www.conf on NetBSD

Tags: php, nginx, netbsd

I'm having issues with `php70-fpm` not including any config files.

I installed `php70-fpm` using `pkgin in php70-fpm`. It installs from here: ftp://ftp.netbsd.org/pub/pkgsrc/packages/NetBSD/earmv6hf/7.1/All/

After installation there is no `www.conf` file anywhere on the system. As a result I am getting errors when trying to start php-fpm:

```
[12-Mar-2017 17:01:42] WARNING: Nothing matches the include pattern '/usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm.d/*.conf' from /usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm.conf at line 125.
[12-Mar-2017 17:01:42] ERROR: No pool defined. at least one pool section must be specified in config file
[12-Mar-2017 17:01:42] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[12-Mar-2017 17:01:42] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

I've searched for `www.conf` using `find / -name "www.conf" ... nothing found.

Should these config files be installed by default or do I have to create them manually? Every other distro I've used includes the files by default.

I've tried removing and reinstalling but that doesn't help.

Any ideas?

**Edit**

Output of `ls -l /usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm*`

```
rpi# ls -l /usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm*
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  4413 Mar 12 17:00 /usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm.conf

/usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm.d:
```

Comment: I see that the error messages refer to no `.conf` files at all and/or no `php-fm.conf` file. So what is the output of `ls -l /usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm*` ?

Comment: @schaiba edited question with output. I's the pool error that's my problem. `www.conf` should exist, but it doesn't. Probably going to have to create it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, BugHunterUK is right, the pkgsrc packages base is:

```
/usr/pkg/
```

that means that the right place for finding *.conf is there, not /usr/local.

Now, to the question, the pool config "www.conf" should be placed in:

```
/usr/pkg/etc/php-fpm.d/
```

In case you do not have it there, search in the examples directory, it is there:

```
/usr/pkg/share/examples/php/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Another thing is, if the package was somehow mispackaged, you can create a config on your own, a nice example can be found here:
https://chris.lu/article/read/50832018268c422808000006

May the PKGSRC be with you!